# ASP.Net Core 7 Razor javascript how to access `wwwroot/image.png`?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, wwwroot

I have the following folder structure:

```
Pages/
  |- Account/
       |- Login/
            |- index.cshtml
  |- Shared/
       |- _Layout.cshtml
|- wwwroot/
    |- 0.png
    |- 1.png
```

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<img id="landing_page_image" src="~/0.png" alt="Login" style="height: 100%; width:100%"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        let img = document.getElementById('landing_page_image');
        img.src = `~/${Math.round(Math.random())}.png`;
    }, 6000);
</script>
```

I get the following error as seen in the browser console:

```
Account/Login/~/1.png 404
```

The path is wrong. How to access `wwwroot/image.png` from the javascript in `_Layout.cshtml`?

Answer (score 2):

The `~` is Razor syntax. When writing Javascript, you need to use the actual path (which is `/1.png`, with the slash defining it as an absolute path).

Answer (score 1):

The `~` operator only works in markup and server side code and not in javascript. Thats why your image url does not get resolved correctly.
To access your image in your `wwwroot` directory simply create the path without the `~` operator:

```
img.src = `/${Math.round(Math.random())}.png`;
```

Answer (score 0):

`~` It should not appear in javascript. The most direct way is to get rid of `~` like below :

```
img.src = `/${Math.round(Math.random())}.png`
```

Comment: `/wwwroot/...` is not accessible, static files are directly located at the web root

Comment: OK. I recognize the problem and have updated it.